# Wordpress 503 error - How do I remove rocket-loader.js from my website?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-503

How do I remove a script from my website that is possibly the source of the 503 error?

```
<script src="https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7089c43e/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js" defer=""></script>
```

When I disabled every plugin, this script still shows up in the page source.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off Rocket Loader for your whole site, click off in the Performance tab of your Cloudflare Dashboard
[image]